# Bash: Default variable with command substitution

Tags: bash, command-substitution, variable-substitution

Is there any way to accomplish the following in one stroke using Bash?

`my_var=${$(grep -E '^setting_1' /settings.conf):-default_setting1}`

As opposed to:

`my_var=$(grep -E '^setting_1' /settings.conf); my_var=${my_var:-default_setting}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can output the default if the grep fails:

```
var=$( grep -e '^setting_1' || echo default_setting )
```

Note that you didn't close the quotes (and without the file argument, grep will filter stdin).

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typos, it was kind of a thoughtless example for the sake of the question.